# How do I send a UDP message from a server using ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, sockets, asp.net-core, udp, asp.net-core-2.1

I am building an application in ASP.NET Core 2.1 that needs to send a UDP message to a server on the local network. I realize that this is not possible from a client's browser. **How do I send server-to-server (or any) packets by UDP in ASP.NET Core 2.1?**

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41270620/3939769) question, but it concerns *receiving* UDP, and a *.NET* application, not ASP.NET.

I have been otherwise unable to find documentation about this.

Comment: See the [UdpClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient).

Comment: @MarkG Thank you! That worked.